# Correcting use of pool on python iterable

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I'm trying to use multithreading.pool to compare images based on similarity. While I have code working on a single core, using a `for loop` or `map()` to iterate over the data, it's dreadfully slow on large groups of images. For that reason I've been trying to implement multiprocessing but I can't seem to get it right. My main question is why doesn't `getssim()` in the below code change the list?

The structure of the iterable looks something like this:

```
[[("images/000.jpg",np.ndarray),0.923],...]
```

Where the float is the simiarlity index of an image compared to the current image being tested. Here is the (somewhat abbreviated) non-working code:

```
import cv2
import glob
from skimage.measure import structural_similarity as ssim
import operator
import multiprocessing

def makeSimilarList(imagesdata):
    simImgList = []  #list of images ordered by their similarity
    while(imagesdata):
        simImg = findSimilar(imagesdata)
        simImgList.append(os.path.basename(simImg))
    return simImgList

def getssim(imgd):
    similarityIndex = ssim(img1,imgd[0][1])
    print(similarityIndex) #this prints correctly
    imgd[1] = similarityIndex 
    return imgd #this appears to have no effect

def findSimilar(imagesdata):
    limg = imagesdata.pop()
    global img1  #making img1 accessible to getssim, a bad idea!
    img1 = limg[0][1]
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),maxtasksperchild=2)
    p.map(getssim,imagesdata)
    p.close()          
    p.join()                                                                     
    imagesdata.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    return limg[0][0]  #return name of image



images = [f for f in glob.glob(src + "*." + ftype)]
images.reverse()
imagesdata = [[(f,cv2.imread(f,0)),""] for f in images]

finalList = makeSimilarList(imagesdata)

with open("./simlist.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(finalList))
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to assign the result from `multiprocessing.map` to a variable. The key function should probably read

```
def findSimilar(imagesdata):
    limg = imagesdata.pop()
    global img1  # making img1 accessible to getssim, a bad idea!
    img1 = limg[0][1]
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(maxtasksperchild=2)
    imagesdata = p.map(getssim, imagesdata)
    p.close()
    p.join()                                                                     
    imagesdata.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    return limg[0][0]  #return name of image
```

Since you don't give enough details, I could not test your code, but I think this was the crucial point.